# Ambiguous reference to LoginManager Facebook sdk swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've integrated facebook-sdk-swift manually in my ios project in xcode8 following documents [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started]. I'm getting error

"Ambiguous reference to member logIn(_:viewController:completion:)"

my code is

```
   loginManager.logIn(["public_profile","email"], viewController: self) { loginResult in switch loginResult { case .Failed(let error): print(error) case .Cancelled: print("User cancelled login.") case .Success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken): print("Logged in!") }
```

Any help please?

Comment: Quickfix should give you a hint. Probably you need to name the first argument `loginManager.logIn(argumentDescription: ["public_profile","email"], viewController:...`

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 code that works:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()        
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile], viewController: nil) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success( _, _, _):
            print("Logged in!")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give enum values for permissions and don't set viewController.

```
//...

loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile, .email], viewController: nil) { results in

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem ,permissions i'm passing in string format which swift compiler not allowing [look here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/95#issuecomment-258909199)

Answer (score 0):

For those who followed ["Facebook Login in Swift - Getting Started"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login) guide and stumbled upon this question, you should replace .PublicProfile with .publicProfile, also cases in LoginResult start from lowercase letters, so replace them too

Answer (score 0):

**XCode 12+:** Switching from Cocoapods version to Swift Package Manager solved the issue.